# unable to connect to the server by using windows powershell remoting

Tags: windows-server-2012, remoteapp

For learning only, with my Windows Server 2012 R2, I would like to set up RemoteApp.

I don't find any help on the web about this error message:

```
unable to connect to the server by using windows powershell remoting
```

or in French:

```
la communication à distance windows powershell ne permet pas la connexion avec le serveur
```

I tried to to run Server Manager with admins rights, but that didn't help.

- What is required to set up this?
- Can you tell me why I get this error message?

Comment: From memory, start the remote registry service, its a prereq.

Comment: Further reading: there is a thread about this on the MS forums. It started in 2012 and is still active. And as of now (2016-07-07) no sure fire way of solving this problem. [*Compatibility problem when installing Remote desktop services role on 2012 "Unable to connect to the server by using Windows Powershell Remoting"*](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bbb7427b-f839-48c4-b49c-467138f94b16/compatibility-problem-when-installing-remote-desktop-services-role-on-2012-unable-to-connect-to-the?forum=winserver8setup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to enable ?

Remote powershell (like ssh but for windows)
or install remoteapp stack (remote desktop services and all the stuff) ?

- To enable windows remote powershell on a server look this FAQ:
  [TechNet Magazine > Home > Tips > Windows PowerShell 2.0 > *Tip: Enable and Use Remote Commands in Windows PowerShell*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx)
- To add remote app stack another one :

  http://www.wackytechtips.com/installing-and-configuring-remote-desktop-services-rds-on-windows-server-2012/

Comment: I wanted to enable Remote PowerShell. Thank you for your help ! (Edit : Vote up impossible under 15 reputation)

Answer (score 0):

Enable Allow Remote Access in My computer properties or server manger > local server >

this will solve your issue